# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty R(x) dx$ converge iff the rational function $R(x)$ has degree of denom. at least 2 degrees higher than numerator?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, rational-functions

I am readinf Ahlfors and came across the fact that:

> $\int_{-\infty}^\infty R(x) dx$, where $R(x)$ is a rational function, converges if and only if in the rational function $R(x)$ the degree of the denominator is at least two units higher than the degree of the numerator.

I am unsure of how to prove this fact rigorously. I do get that the condition on the degrees means roughly that $R(x)$ is approximately $\frac cx$ (whose integral diverges) with $c$ a constant, but could anyone post a rigorus proof of this?

Comment: You mean $\int_1^\infty$, right? It's basically because $\int_1^x\frac{dx} x$ doesn't converge, yet $\int_1^x\frac{dx} {x^2}$ does.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx$ doesn't converge, though. However, that's because of the pole in the middle, not because of the tails at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @Ennar thanks, would you elaborate using epsilon-delta approximations and I'll select yours as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need an extra assumption on zeros of the denominator. For example $\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ is not integrable. Let $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and degree of $q$ is at least $2$ more than the degree of $p$ and let us assume that the denominator has no zeros on $\mathbb R$. Then there is a constant $C$ such that $|\frac p q |\leq \frac C {x^{2}}$ for $|x|$ sufficiently large and this makes $R=\frac p q$ integrable.

Comment: I also seek to prove this statement. In particular, that for sufficiently large ${\left| z \right|}$ there is a constant $k$ for which $\left| {f(z)} \right| < {k \over {{{\left| z \right|}^2}}}$ In which source have you seen these relationships? Can you introduce it to me?

Comment: I have asked this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702165/if-fx-is-a-real-rational-function-with-denominator-of-degree-at-least-two-un